# Some Byobu shortcuts not working when using the Secure Shell extension from a Chromebook

Tags: ssh, chromebook, byobu

While SSH-ing to a Linux workstation using the [Secure Shell Chrome extension](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) from my Chromebook, *most* of Byobu's keyboard shortcuts work fine (using `tmux` underneath). One notable exception is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> for switching between sessions(*), which are interpreted as simple <kbd>Up/Down</kbd> key presses and scroll through my bash command history.

How can I have access to switching between sessions on this environment?

Ideally there's some extension settings combination that would fix this, but I couldn't find the right incantation myself (I'm not an expert by any means). But maybe there are other ways or workarounds, like creating [new Byobu shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208369/modify-key-bindings-in-byobu) or using alternative [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-based shortcuts](https://gist.github.com/PackeTsar/e4adf2a2056710a0b65c537fd2990188)?.

In case that helps, these are the sequences I get using `read -n 1` from the Secure Shell extension:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: `^[[5~`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: `^[[6~`

And from a local terminal on the workstation:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>: `^[[1;3A`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>: `^[[1;3B`

(*): Curiously, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> work just fine. There are other shortcuts that do not work either, but I'm less bothered by them, like <kbd>F4</kbd>-based ones (used by the OS for maximize/restore of windows) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Are you using ChromeOS? It is off topic on this site. Only Ubuntu and its official flavors are on topic

Comment: However, you can install ubuntu on a Chromebook https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466 If you have a more specific question about installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook, I will be happy to answer

Comment: I am using a Chromebook to connect to a Linux box, so it's likely off topic. Sorry about that... Could you guide me to which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate for this question?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I posted a [mirror question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/748453/some-byobu-shortcuts-not-working-when-using-the-secure-shell-extension-from-a-ch) at that site. But I couldn't find how to close this one, or mark it as off topic. Feel free to do that, if you can.