# I am having trouble using crouton on ChromeOS

Tags: chromebook, chromeos, crouton

I downloaded **crouton** using the ling provided on the ubuntu site. when i run

> `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t unity`

i get the following

> `sh: 0: Refusing to exec /home/chronos/user/Downloads/crouton from noexec mount; see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/security/noexec_shell_scripts.md`

I tried

> `sudo mount -o remount,exec,suid,dev,symfollow /home/chronos/user/Downloads/`

which i found in another question asked almost exactly like this one to no avail.

What am i missing?

Comment: How are we to know?  We don't know what OS/release you're using, and you didn't provide a link to the instructions you are attempting to follow so its possible you're misunderstanding the detail. The

Comment: Crouton hosts Ubuntu 16.04, which is unsupported. Here is how to install full Ubuntu (not a virtual machine/chroot) on a Chromebook https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466