# VIsual Studio Code on Linux (Debian) environment chromebook - dependency issues

Tags: dependencies, chromebook, visual-studio-code

I follow the steps to install VS code on Chromebook amd64 (https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started) and get stuck on double-click on the package to launch the installer.

I see:
Install app with Linux
Installation successfully started.
Details
Application: code
Version: 1.81.0-1690979901
Description: Code editing. Redefined.
Visual Studio Code is a new choice of tool that combines the simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for the core edit-build-debug cycle. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux for installation instructions and FAQ.

I click OK and see Error installing Linux application

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

code: Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.17) but it is not installable

```
    Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not installable
    Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
    Depends: libatspi2.0-0 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not installable
    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
    Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
    Depends: libcurl3-gnutls but it is not installable or
             libcurl3-nss but it is not installable or
             libcurl4 but it is not installable or
             libcurl3 but it is not installable
    Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not installable
    Depends: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.60) but it is not installable
    Depends: libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libgbm1 (>= 17.1.0~rc2) but it is not installable
    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0) but it is not installable
    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.39.4) but it is not installable
    Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 but it is not installable
    Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable
    Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not installable or
             libgtk-4-1 but it is not installable
    Depends: libkrb5-3 but it is not installable
    Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable
    Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.22) but it is not installable
    Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.26) but it is not installable
    Depends: libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not installable
    Depends: libsecret-1-0 (>= 0.18) but it is not installable
    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but it is not installable
    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but it is not installable
    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but it is not installable
    Depends: libx11-6 but it is not installable
    Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not installable
    Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.4.4-1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libxext6 but it is not installable
    Depends: libxfixes3 but it is not installable
    Depends: libxkbcommon0 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libxkbfile1 but it is not installable
    Depends: libxrandr2 but it is not installable
    Recommends: libvulkan1 but it is not installable
```

I mean, I understand nothing. I would just like to set up local web dev environment to start coding after codecademy course and web says my Chromebook should install VS Code and all other dependencies.

Pleeease if anyone could advice i would be more than grateful!
karo

---

ok so I removed Linux dev environment and  installed it again, adding sudo apt-get -f install and then following the steps from here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-debian-10/ on how to install VS Code on Debian10. No idea if thats what i was meant to do, but works.

If i double click on the file from the downloads, the errors are still same as before. I launched VS Code from the command line with 'code'.

If anyone has any idea what just happened feel free to share.

Comment: The Linux environment in Chromebook is Debian 11, and not Ubuntu. Debian is off-topic here.  To install full Ubuntu in Chromebook, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017/1469237#1469237) answer. There VS Code can be installed with .deb/flatpak/snap in the usual way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

or use aptitude to fix co dependencies

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install changes nothing

Comment: how do i use aptitude to fix codependencies?

Comment: go_girl@penguin:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.