# trying to install chrx but keep getting "failure writing output to destination"

Tags: output

I am totally new at all this. I bought a chromebook and want to be able to run music editing software on it. I found how to install Linux and open a terminal and all that. I tried to download chroot and couldn't get it to work and then I saw someone post about chrx. I downloaded the raw data and followed the README on github.This is what I get:

chronos@alan-rev3 / $ curl https://chrx.org/ | sudo tar xzfc - /usr/local && chrx
tar: You may not specify more than one '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or  '--test-label' option
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Comment: This isn't the Linux Q&A site (SE *Unix & Linux* covers Linux and Unix questions), but a Ubuntu Q&A site. What Ubuntu product & release did you install?

Comment: You don't need chrx to install GNU/Linux apps on a Chromebook. It has a preinstalled containerized Debian 11 environment (see https://www.laptopmag.com/how-to/install-linux-apps-on-your-chromebook). You can also install Android apps. If these do not work for you, you might want to install full Ubuntu on a Chromebook. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017?noredirect=1&lq=1 for that

Comment: This site is for Ubuntu. ChromeOS is not supported here. Chromebook questions are supported if you are running Ubuntu on a Chromebook, or your question is about installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook