# fresh dual boot used mrchromebox and chrx. attempting linux boot and presented with "/syslinux/vmlinuz" not found

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, live-usb, chromebook

using mrchromebox and chrx, i successfully partitioned and used chrx -d xubuntu modifier to install linux rather than USB.
booting into grub, it shows

> error:file /syslinux/cmlinuz.A not found,

> press any key to contiunue

> Failed to tboot both default and fallback entries

Ive been using linux for years now and generally successfully navigated problems and command line use up to know but am still not amazing. though i am a bit stumped with how to proceed. with some research i think it seems the grub is not looking in the right directory or partition or something.

I have tried Booting of a liveUSB with the intention of writing a new xubuntu install to the partition but I cant seem to boot a liveUSB. Following online tutorials, i have set dev_boot_usb=1, but when I try to boot from developer mode with "boot from external drive", I am promted with

> no valid image detected, make sure your external disk has a valid chromeOS

Which obviously im trying to boot a linux OS not chromeOS

Having read around some people short hand mention using arch chroot, mounting files, then running pacman command. I dont totally grasp these steps but found out archISO needs to be booted liveUSB but that seems ruled out because i cant boot from USB as mentioned above. I can still boot into chromosOS, if this offers some path to repairing the linux partition. Or is it safe to try run the chrx process again? im cautious it will just divide a new partitoin out of what space is left instead of overwriting the failed linux install.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to proceed here in a digestable way?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you asking about?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run `lsb_release -a` and [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500634/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on an Intel/AMD Chromebook (e.g. Google Pixelbook 2017)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-intel-amd-chromebook-e-g-google-pixelbook-2017)