# Upgrading an old Chromebook to Ubuntu

Tags: chromebook

Rookie here. I have a 12 year old Samsung Chromebook that I want to switch to a Linux machine. No need for dual booting. I've searched for instructions but haven't found any for a rookie like me that makes enough sense. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to upgrade Chrome OS to Ubuntu. Usually, you'd go for a kind of dual boot, and there are many plain English howtos: [1](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook) ... [2](https://www.lifewire.com/install-linux-on-chromebook-4125253) I think a 12 year old machine is too old, and you've posted nothing about the hardware specs, so it may or may not work.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu on a chromebook without dual booting. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1469237/243321

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on an Intel/AMD Chromebook (Google Pixelbook 2017)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-intel-amd-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017)

Comment: Such an old Chromebook will not be able to handle Ubuntu. Use a lightweight OS, like Raspberry Pi OS for PC instead https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/