how to upgrade to 24.04 from 14.04 with command line
I have an older computer with 14.04 installed. I stopped using it as I could never get the nvidia card to work after the upgrade from 14.02. It exceeds the minimum hardware requirements. (I used my windows 10 laptop at my volunteer activity and then it died.)
After lots of reading, it is probably not a good idea to try to 'update'.
I used kubuntu and ubuntu for years and do not have the need to 'try it out'. I have copied my docs and photos to a flash drive.
I would like to get a clean,fresh install of 24.04.
I am not proficient with the command line. What I have found on Ask Ubuntu is more complex than I understand. It can't be that hard, or is it?
Any help for an Octo-newbie?
Bill

You've not said if this was a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server install, as they differ in regards options; you also mention 14.02 which means what? as Ubuntu didn't have a release in 2014-February so what was 14.02 as there was no Ubuntu release then. I might consider a non-destructive re-install (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533 but would be easier to 22.04 or using a flavor at 24.04) but I'd explore what exactly you used the system for, inc. apps first due to jump (lots of change in a decade!) but its not command line

If older computer Kubuntu or a light weight flavor may work better. Ubuntu now is for newer systems with more hardware capability. Is system UEFi or BIOS? I typically zsync ISO and if only if UEFI, use 7zip to extract ISO into FAT32 formatted partition with boot,esp flags. If BIOS, you have to have a BIOS boot loader installed also which is what most install tools do. If UEFI I can post commands I use.

For installing ubuntu on chromebook, check out https://askubuntu.com/q/1468964/124466

A clean install of 24.04 follows the same process you used to install 14.04.

Create a LiveUSB installer

Step-by-step tutorial to create a Live USB on your Chromebook:
https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/106814843/how-to-create-a-ubuntu-bootable-usb-drive-on-my-chromebook?hl=en


Boot from that LiveUSB, and
Follow the prompts


Thanks 733, but I don't have a working graphical interface on my 14.04. Can I download the file from Ubuntu to download folder on my Chromebook? How would I write the ISO image to the flash? Then move the flash to my desktop. Or, what is the terminal command to do this? Thanks very much..Bill

Edited the answer to a Chromebook-specific link.
